# pass image from popup child window to parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to pass an image from a popup child form to the parent form.

Parent Form script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var popup;
      function SelectSig() {
      popup = window.open("Popup.htm", "Popup", "width=600,height=300");
      popup.focus();
      }
    </script>
```

parent form button

```
     <input type="button" value="Insert Signature" onclick="SelectSig()" /></td>
```

Child Form script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function SetSig() {
    if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
        var ClientSig = window.opener.document.getElementById("ClientSig");
        ClientSig.src = document.getElementById("saveSignature").src;
       window.close();
        }


   </script>
```

Child Form button

```
      <input type="button" value="Select" onclick="SetSig();" />
```

Comment: You should post what is happening vs what you are expecting to happen.

Comment: Noted, the parent page is opening the popup window, but when i click save nothing is happening

Comment: sorry i have not used fiddle before, does it work for two pages